# Does Dharma reduces from one mahayuga to another mahayuga?

Tags: dharma, yuga

In each mahayuga there a four yugas. It is well known that dharma reduces from Krita yuga to Kali yuga.

Is there any such change in Dharma from one mahayuga to its next mahayuga?

Comment: excellent question. one sholka says - dharma samsthapanarthaya sambhavami yuge yuge. sthapana - establishment. sam-sthapana - well establishment. so,  when kali has to change to krita yuga, if Bhagavan himself says he's gonna establish it 'well', we can expect it to be done well. this is just my opinion.